# Unable to connect to Gerrit SSHD

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to setup `gerrit`, but I guess I am missing some configuration as I am unable to connect to `gerrit sshd`.   [This guide](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.5.1/install-quick.html) is what I am trying to follow. The web interface is opening up and I was able to register. However when I try `ssh user@my.example.net -p 29418` I am getting a `Connection refused`. I have verified that gerrit is indeed running.

Gerrit is running behind `nginx` and these are the configuration I have so far:
Nginx config:

```
server {
server_name my.example.net;

 location / {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8090;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    include conf/proxy.conf;
    auth_basic "Admin";
    include conf/auth.conf;
 }
}
```

Part of gerrit.config:

```
[auth]
    type = HTTP
[sshd]
    listenAddress = 127.0.0.1:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-http://127.0.0.1:8090/
```

The firewall is indeed allowed to accept connections on port `29418`

```
# iptables -L -n | grep 29418
  ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:29418
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx has no influence on Gerrit's SSHd and you can't (AFAIK) proxy them through it.

You've configured Gerrit to listen on localhost (`sshd.listenAddress = 127.0.0.1:29418`), so you can't connect from remote. Just drop that line and it will listen to all interfaces by default, I guess that's what you want.

You can verify that through `netstat -ntlp | grep 29418`. It must show `0.0.0.0:29418` as listening address, not `127.0.0.1:29418`.

Comment: Thanks.. that helped. Never knew that listening on `localhost` would prevent connections from outside.

Comment: well, that's basically exactly what's `localhost` for ;-)